How do I access FastAPI URL from my docker application?
I have a front end react application hosted on a subdomain (www.admin.example.com). I also have a backend application that uses FastAPI to communicate with the front-end react application. This backend application is deployed using docker. The front end is built using npm run build command and deployed manually i.e build files are copied to the subdomain's root directory.
I am however having issues accessing this FastAPI backend application which is hosted using docker. I have tried using the IP address of my server + the port (https://server_ip_address:8000) but I do not get the response set on the / path from my FastAPI backend. That url (https://server_ip_address:8000), in fact, doesn't load a page. I get the error: This site can’t be reached.
But when I access https://server_ip_address I get a page loaded talking about nginx. I checked the docker logs and there's no error or response from the FastAPI application. I was told docker has it's own IP address too but I tried that and it doesn't work. I also can't access a URL such as https://server_ip_address:8000 from my front-end application else I get a CORS policy error. The overall question is, how do I access my FastAPI application listening on docker?
Docker Compose File:
services:
  db:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    secrets:
      - MONGODB_URI
      - LOGIN_SECRET_KEY

secrets:
  LOGIN_SECRET_KEY:
    file: admin_login_secret_key.txt
  MONGODB_URI:
    file: mongo_db_uri.txt

Docker File:
# Use an official Python runtime as a base image
FROM python:3.9

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY . .

# Specify the command to run on container start
CMD ["uvicorn", "db:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

Server nginx.conf File (Only the server setting)
server {
        listen 8080;
    server_name admin.example.com;

    location /backend/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}

I tried accessing like this https://admin.example.com:8080/backend but it doesn't route to http://127.0.0.1:8000.

The docker compose file has only the db service; it does not have the web service.  Where is the web service defined?

@JohnGordon If by the web service you mean the react application, it wasn't built with docker. It's a separate application

Is curl http://localhost:8000 working ?

@Philippe is that supposed to work in production?

I guess not, that's only a troubleshooting step, as you have not provided the details of your network configuration.

@Philippe What details? I am new to this lol, so sorry if I'm slow. I have the IP address of my subdomain. I don't know what other configuration you are talking about

For example, is server_ip_address an IP address visible on the internet, or only visible on your local network ? and what do you mean by domain IP address and server IP address ?

@Philippe It's the IP address visible on the internet. For example, IP address found using this site: https://www.nslookup.io/website-to-ip-lookup/.
domain IP address and server IP address are the same thing for me. I believe that's the same for everyone lol.

your host is probably also running nginx (in addition to the container) if you get a response from an instance of it .. does it work if you drop the compose instance and just configure the host's? I also doubt your proxy_pass setting is correct and you should set it via an env var (which can be db in the docker-compose file)

@Philippe I made some edits to the post for more clarity.

@ti7 If I access the domain name and port eg https://admin.example.com:8000, I get a site can't be reached error.
If I use the IP address of the server along with the port eg https://38.281.00:8000, I get the same error.
But If I access just the IP address, I get a page showing that nginx was setup properly.
The way I currently set it up now was with help of ChatGPT but it doesn't work.

that's ok, it will mislead you as long as you allow, and when it can mislead an expert in their field, it will be complete - skimming the official docs, try their example of just running the FastAPI app without nginx in the way https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/#start-the-docker-container

@Philippe When I do telnet 127.0.0.1 8000 through ssh, it is received on my docker container, however doing http://127.0.0.1 doesn't work through the main react application. I get connection refused.

@ti7 When I do telnet 127.0.0.1 8000 or curl -i http://127.0.0.1:8000 through ssh, I get a valid response from the docker container, however doing http://127.0.0.1:8000 doesn't work through the browser. I get connection refused.

Have you checked nginx log file ?

Please check the following possible reasons:

You have not configured Nginx properly. If you want to access your FastAPI application via the ip address and 80 port, you will need to configure a reverse proxy mapping port 80 to port 8000.
Your security policy restricts the 8000 port. Therefore, you cannot access port 8000 externally. That's why https://ip_address:8000 does not work.

Some advice:

Configure a reverse proxy for your backend instead of trying to access it through ip address and port. Personally, I will put built React file in the www root and proxy /api to my backend server.


Please check the updated post. I did exactly that but it still doesn't work. One detail I left out is that my domain is a subdomain. So other projects are hosted on that domain. Would this affect accessing the 8000 port?

@AlexanderObidiegwu If your nginx is configured in your docker container, then server_name is actually redundant. It is only useful when you have to deal with requests with different domains.

@AlexanderObidiegwu A subdomain is actually a DNS record in the domain. For example, www.subdomain.example.com is actually a DNS record named www.subdomain in example.com, which contains the IP address of the server.

@AlexanderObidiegwu Normally, HTTP service listens on port 80. But you seem to listen on port 8000. You may need to visit www.subdomain.example.com:8000. Do you have the access to nginx configuration in your host server (instead of docker container)? If you do, you can add configuration of www.subdomain.example.com which listens on 80, and is reverse proxied to localhost:8000.

I tried doing that but nothing works. Reversed proxy in every shape and form but it doesn't yield any result. My FastAPI application doesn't receive the request. But this works when I do curl -i http:127.0.01:8000 or telnet 127.0.0.1 8000. Also work with localhost:8000.
I have deleted the nginx service from my docker. It only contains my fastAPI application now

I update the post to show what I am currently doing.

@AlexanderObidiegwu From the information you've provided so far, I come to the following conclusion: your FastAPI application works successfully. So maybe the problem is about your Nginx configuration. For example, you tried to visit via https, but from your configuration I didn't see any https settings, like your certificate file location. So maybe you can try to visit through http. Also, you can check your nginx access log to see whether nginx really received a request from you.

Thanks! You were right. It was from nginx configuration and firewall issues. The team in charge of those lent me a hand. Thank you. It's fixed now
